# Message passing interface (MPI)on Windows

Tags: windows, messaging

I an new to MPI and i want to use it under windows. Please could any one give me a link in which i can download this library (if exist). If there are many versions of MPI i hope to be referred to the most linux like because i have an MPI C linux code and i want with minimal change to make it work on windows.
Thanks very much 
Hani Almousli.......

Answer (score 1):

[MPICH](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2/downloads/index.php?s=downloads).

In case your existing code uses linux-specific code, consider using `gcc` from [MINGW](http://www.mingw.org/) or [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) for compilation.

Answer (score 1):

You can download and install Microsoft HPC pack 2008 SDK which includes MSMPI (based on mpich)

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=12887da1-9410-4a59-b903-693116bfd30e&displaylang=en

If you have been using mpich and would like to stay with it then just install the one from ANL site.

http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2/downloads/index.php?s=downloads